# Looking for a server side rendering package for Angular 1.5 application

Tags: angularjs

TLDR Google bots are seeing angular variables on the public side our application instead of the dynamic text that we have set up to display.

Hello! I am looking for a good recommendation for a server-side rendering or a pretending service that I can use for an Angular 1.5 application. The biggest problem that I am facing is that we don't use NodeJS and all the prerenders seem to require it.

Our local development uses docker with nginx, php7, angular 1.5, MySQL database and elastic search containers. We also use ant, composer, and npm if that helps any. Apologies in advance as I am quite new to prerendering, but im eager to learn if anyone can help!

I was pointed to (https://github.com/ng-consult/ng1-server/blob/master/README.md) by a coworker but I can't seem to get the dependencies for that repo installed on my machine (mac 10.13.2). I suspect this requires Node so that may be why its not working...
[image: what i get after running npm install -g ng1-server]
Thank you!